# Rollback changes on question?

Tags: discussion

There is a user that has made 4 different edits on [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/84/99) and all edits are only on the question's tags. After the four edits, the questions is as it was originally with one added tag.
If I remember correctly a question with 5 edits will become a wiki questions, so wouldn't it be better to rollback all changes?

Comment: Sorry for the editing, the initial edits were due to confusion, then attempting to set them back. I would vote to roll back the edits, as you point out, they are the same with a single addition. I would roll them back myself if I knew how and/or had the capability. I did not realize that a number of edits would change the question. Apparently I need to go back through the rules governing the site, and as such will refrain from making changes until I better understand the consequences.

Comment: No worries. I don't have enough reputation to do a rollback either, that's why I posted this question. Hopefully an moderator can fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rollbacks won't prevent anything - the previous edits are still stored in the system and remain with their previous effect. It will in fact just add another record into the edit history.

That said, [previous testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60923/which-edit-actions-can-move-a-post-into-community-wiki-mode) done long ago shows that the *only* kind of edit that can push a post towards Community Wiki status is a body edit. The question directly linked demonstrates a complete history of retags without any community wiki being triggered - neither by volume nor by author count. Since those are all of the edits on the question you're worried about, nothing should happen until it naturally hits the required number of body edits.

Going forward, if a post does become Community Wiki and it really shouldn't, you may always flag these posts for moderator attention and explain why it shouldn't be wiki. A moderator can reverse the wiki process, which also doubles to prevent it from further becoming wiki automatically from any further edits.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!